# SQL query - issue with WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query, which is made from snippets/ideas around here - I am not an expert in the more advanced SQL yet. The part I want you to focus on is: WHERE ... l.status='active'

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(c.id) AS callsNum 
FROM leads AS l 
LEFT JOIN calls AS c ON c.lead = l.id
WHERE l.pool IN ($pools) AND l.status='active' AND l.center='$center'
GROUP BY l.id
ORDER BY callsNum ASC, l.id ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

I can't get the error myself, but some people has experienced errors where leads with a status that is not "active" has come up.

Can anyone spot the error? I suppose the code can be better too, any suggestions are welcome - if it ain't clear what the code is supposed to do, feel free to ask.

UPDATE:

Thanks for all your responses. I'm glad you think the query should work. I suppose I need to add some more info.

The system is for a small callcenter. The query is getting the next lead from the selected pools, that the caller should call to. In the same AJAX call to the PHP file the "next lead" gets marked as "processing" to avoid multiple callers getting the samme lead.

As pointed out the problem could technically happen if two callers pressed the "get next lead" button on the exact same time. But they have reported to me, that even if they are just 2 callers calling on the same pools at the same time, they get the same lead quite often. If they are 4 callers, even more often.

I therefore put in some lines of code just after this query, that checks one more time that the lead has status='active' - and if not, it comes up with an error (to prevent multiple callers calling at the same time). This error comes quite often, and I therefore suspect that something is wrong with this query.

It is very important that a lead won't come up multiple times. Any suggestions?

RELEVANT CODE (FULL)

Here is a longer code example as requested. The error in the end comes up quite often with just 2-4 persons using it (on a quite fast server).

```
// Get next lead
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT l.*, COUNT(c.id) AS callsNum 
    FROM leads AS l 
    LEFT JOIN calls AS c ON c.lead = l.id
    WHERE l.pool IN ($pools) AND l.status='active' AND l.center='$center'
    GROUP BY l.id
    ORDER BY callsNum ASC, l.id ASC
    LIMIT 0,1");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 

if($res->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

        // Set as "processing" to avoid simultaneous call from multiple bookers 
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE leads SET status='processing' WHERE status='active' AND id=? AND center='$center'");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $row["id"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $affectedRows = $stmt->affected_rows;
        if($affectedRows != 1) {
            echo 'ERROR. Please reload.';
            die;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are selecting non aggregate columns, which is technically bad, but other than this I don't see any problem.  What is your current output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . It should be fine in this case, assuming the `id` is unique in `leads`.

Comment: where looks ok. Can it be that you're getting ` active` or ` active    ` columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sure it will work, just pointing out that it should be avoided.

Comment: Does that query fails in execution or it just outputs wrong data? That was not clear!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this means "You are selecting non aggregate columns". Question updated with more information. @llouk wrong data

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard by "non-aggregate columns" he means columns that are neither being calculated using functions such as count, sum, max, etc... nor listed in the group by clause. In most other RDBMDS this is not legal syntax, it can lead to unpredictable results in MySQL unless you are grouping on a field that guarantees unique results for all non-aggregated fields; for example, if you selected a specific field from calls, which related calls row the field is pulled from is indeterminate.

Comment: Please post a full query, including the statement where you are setting the lead as "inactive". If lead is not set as "inactive" immediatly after initial select, then concurency is a likely cause. Another suggestion is to use transactions and table hints to lock specific records.

Comment: @Alex - updated now as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I can't get the error myself, but some people has experienced errors
>   where leads with a status that is not "active" has come up.

This can be a concurrency problem, where while user A is getting a list of leads (using your query) and reading them, another user (user B) marks one of leads as "inactive" at the same time. So when User A then opens a lead it is marked as "inactive".
If User A refreshes a list that lead would no longer be there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would have less concurrency issues, but you could try something **like** this first to 'reserve' the lead:

```
UPDATE leads 
SET status = CONCAT('Processing ', somesortofcalleridentifier) 
WHERE l.pool IN ($pools) AND l.status='active' AND l.center='$center'
LIMIT 1;
```

I say *like* this because your original ordering by a grouping result will probably make it a bit more complicated than what I've shown.

then follow up with:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(c.id) AS callsNum 
FROM leads AS l 
LEFT JOIN calls AS c ON c.lead = l.id
WHERE status = CONCAT('Processing ', somesortofcalleridentifier)
;
```

Comment: Thanks! If this code is used, how can it get concurrency issues? To me it looks quite good.

Comment: It won't have any that I am aware of, but most of the time I've spent with MySQL was on a project that predated and (as can be guessed) continued to ignore the availability of transactions, etc... So while I don't expect there to be issues, I can't 100% guarantee there won't be.

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard it basically turns the status field into a makeshift mutex; but the more complicated the UPDATE, the more I worry the operation will not be effectively atomic.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds quite promising. I am not familiar with CONCAT - what should "somesortofcalleridentifier" be? Some sort of (quite) unique string for each call, like ex md5(random string + userID)? The query: this way the "callsNum" should be in the UPDATE query, as it is used to determine what lead that should be selected. callsNum is 1st sort-parameter, after that comes id. Is this still possible?

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard I would guess you don't need anything too extravagant for the caller identifier. I would guess you have some sort of unique identifier for each entity that pulls leads in this manner; that should suffice. As far as using the original callNum, you might actually be able to use your original select (but with a larger LIMIT) and just loop through those results attempting an update similar to the one I provided until you get a records affected of 1.

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard Actually, looking at the original code you added, I am not sure how they are having a problem... though I am not sure what you do with the id after a update with affected rows == 1. I would expect users to receive not infrequent "Reload" messages, but not acquisition of leads other users are processing. *Technically/pedantically, all leads retrieved should be not "active", since they are not accepted unless set to "processing".*

Answer (score 0):

In the Where part, it says we need table leads which its attributes have some special characteristics to satisfy all three conditions as below:

1. `l.pool` should be in set (`$pools`)
2. `l.status` should be active
3. `l.center` should be `$center`

Comment: Is this an answer?